# Find the elements of the left coset a^2⟨(a^5)(b^1)⟩ in D11.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Find the elements of the left coset a^2⟨(a^5)(b^1)⟩ in D11.
Enter your answer as a comma separated list; make sure each coset representation is of the form (e1,e2) where e1 represents the exponent for a and e2 represents the exponent for b.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @kccu I have got the order of D11 as 22. a is a rotation, b a reflection. Rotations can be calculated as a^k= 360*k/n

Comment: Yes but do you understand what $\langle a^5b\rangle$ means? Do you understand how to write $ba$ in the form $a^ib^j$?

Comment: @almagest no, I am not sure

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have probably been introduced to $D_{11}$ as symmetry operations on a regular $11$-gon with $a$ as a rotation, and $b$ as a reflection.

The angle brackets mean the subgroup generated by the element $a^5b$. So the first step is to figure out what its elements are.

If you know any geometry, you should know that any combination of rotations and a reflection is a reflection. So $a^5b$ must be a reflection and hence has order 2. So the only other element of $\langle a^5b\rangle$ is 1.

Now all you have to do is premultiply the two elements by $a^2$ to get the coset $\{a^7b,a^2\}$ or in their notation $\{(7,1),(2,0)\}$

---

Alternatively, go down the algebraic route. In that case you need to know that $ba=a^{-1}b$. So you start by squaring $a^5b$ to see what you get: $$a^5ba^5b=a^5(ba)a^4b=a^5(a^{-1}b)a^4b=a^4ba^4b=\dots =b^2=1$$

So the subgroup $\langle a^5b\rangle$ only has two elements: $a%5b$ and 1 and you premultiply by $a^2$ to get the answer.

Comment: Thank You so much. I knew that any combination of rotations and a reflection is a reflection, but it didn't come to mind. If it did come to mind I would have gotten the rest. Thank you again.